# About how sorting answers based on votes works

Tags: discussion, up-votes

When the answers to a question are sorted by number of votes, I see that the accepted answer appears on the top, even though another answer has more votes. Is there a reason for it to work like this. My opinion is that the answer with the highest number of votes should appear on top even if another answer has been accepted. Sometimes, a better answer may be posted **after** another answer was already accepted, and the better answer may get more votes over time.

Answer (score 4):

The system is set up so that the OP's decision/opinion takes priority over vote count.

Not saying I agree with it. It's just the way it (currently) is.

Here's the [main discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) from Stack Overflow's Meta.

Comment: Thanks, Richard! This is just my opinion that, if I explicitly ask to sort by votes, only the number of votes should be taken into consideration. This should not be taken to imply that any answer is better than another. Anyone's decision or opinion should not be of any concern here. Just my opinion. I will go with whatever the powers-that-be may decide.

Comment: And thanks for the link to that discussion. Seems to be a very interesting one. Will read more of it at leisure.

Comment: I think I agree with your opinion :-)